# Cannot call method 'lat' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-chrome

So good morning,

I'm working on a project witch includes google maps.
Everything working so fine, i (thought) was finished with the part of coding the maps but then it hit me. Testing my project on firefox OK, testing it on Chrome 568 errors (@#$%@#).

So what caused all this mess? I load my page, the one with the maps(on chrome), everything ok but after about a minute my marker vanish from canvas and scrolling the mouse over the map cause all these errors.

So i thought, ok i've done some thing really bad but why not in firefox. Being more patient than some minutes, the problem is there it is not like on chrome where i can see it always, but some times it is happening there too.

So the code part

[Link to my file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52031434/maps.js)

sorry about the link, but its a bit of code.

If i find my solution, i post to save you from my hell.

Thanks in advance all of you(and sorry for my english)!

Comment: What line in your file does the error occur on?  And, exactly what od you do or call to make the error occur.  You need to give us more details to go on rather than just dump a large JS file on us with no directions as to where to look or study.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your replay, my console sais main.js lines 9 ,19 ,20 i think this is the maps files so i guess i'm doing something wrong but there is no error for line in my code.
Sorry about the large file but im in blank stop my own, i would not ask for help if i had an error line on my code i could solve.
Both browsers says my maps.js in clean!!!!!

Comment: Then, I'd suggest you go put a breakpoint on the lines in `main.js` that generate the errors and look back at the stack trace to see which line of yours is calling them.  Perhaps you are calling something with the wrong arguments or a null argument.

Comment: @jfriend00 the main.js is stored at google serve how could i see it??

ok i found it.Thanks i'll try it.

Comment: You can see it in any javascript debugger such as the one built into Chrome.  Chrome can even decompress it to make it more readable.  In the debugger, you can set breakpoints in it - it does not matter what server the file is hosted on.  If it's referenced by your page, you can see it and set breakpoints in it in the debugger.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, you saved me and it was so childish of me.
Last night i move the goolge maps api from head to foot, was try to make it load a bit faster.
So i move the api but my functions remained on the head file......
After midnight working can be so hard......